# problem on returning value of function as a list using if

Tags: equation-solving, version-9

today i was writing a function for my project using mathematica that gives a line equation in form of $y=mx+b$ and a circle equation in form of $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and finds the intersection point which is on the left side of circle($x<0$)

```
intersectionPoint[eqLine_, eqCircle_] :=
Module[{eq1 = eqLine, eq2 = eqCircle, pts, x1, x2, a},
    pts = NSolve[eq1 && eq2, {x, y}];
    x1 = x /. pts[[1, 1]];
    x2 = x /. pts[[2, 1]];
    if[x1 < 0, a = pts[[1]], a = pts[[2]]];
    a
 ];
```

So for a input like this

```
b = intersectionPoint[y == 0*x + 4, x^2 + y^2 == 25]
```

I expect b should be equal to this

```
{x -> -3., y -> 4.}
```

but instead it returns

```
{x -> 3., y -> 4.}
```

I read the [wolfram If reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) and in Generalizations part there was something like this

```
In[1]:=x = -2;
If[x < 0, y = -x, y = x]; y
Out[1]= 2
```

I can't understand why my function does not give me my expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple typos in your code, the most glaring being the lower-case `if`.  This seems to work,

```
intersectionPoint[eqLine_, eqCircle_] := 
  Module[{eq1 = eqLine, eq2 = eqCircle, pts, x1, x2, a},
         pts = NSolve[eq1 && eq2, {x, y}];
         x1 = x /. pts[[1]];
         x2 = x /. pts[[2]];
         If[x1 < 0, a = pts[[1]], a = pts[[2]]];
         a];
```